# Sum numbers if cell contains X and store in another table

Tags: ms-access

So if we have two columns 'Domain' and 'Score'. There are duplicate domains with different scores. How would I add all the scores together that are from the same domain?

and furthermore, how do I then show it separately in another table?

Thanks,

Leon.

Answer (score 1):

query look like this.

```
SELECT Domain, sum(NZ(Score,0)) as total FROM yourtable group by Domain
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :)